# How to use WebRTC with RTCPeerConnection on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

I would like to build a web application that processes video from users' webcams. It looks like WebRTC is ideal for this project. But, I'm having a hard time creating a peer connection between the user's machine and a pod in my Kubernetes cluster. How would you connect these two peers?

This question on Server Fault discusses the issue I'm running into: [WEBRTC MCU/SFU inside kubernetes - Port Ranges](https://serverfault.com/questions/954715/webrtc-mcu-sfu-inside-kubernetes-port-ranges). WebRTC wants a bunch of ports open so users can create peer connections with the server but Kubernetes has ports closed by default. Here's a rephrasing of my question: How to create
RTCPeerConnections connecting multiple users to an application hosted in a Kubernetes cluster? How should network ports be setup?

The closest I've come to finding a solution is [Orchestrating GPU-accelerated streaming apps using WebRTC](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/orchestrating-gpu-accelerated-streaming-apps-using-webrtc), their code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/selkies-vdi). I don't fully understand their approach, I believe it depends on [Istio](https://istio.io/).

Comment: "How would you connect these two peers?" well, webrtc uses STUN/TURN to connect through NAT... it is a bit more complicated protocol, yes. Can you clarify what part you ask about?

Comment: you can have the same architecture without Istio as well

Comment: @Jonas thanks for the help! I have been using https://www.xirsys.com/ for STUN/TURN servers. I have been using https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc for my server-side code. When I run my server-side code on my personal computer users can connect. When I run the same code in my Kubernetes cluster users cannot connect. I think I need to open up the network so peer connections can be made with pods in the cluster, but I haven't figured out the best way to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The document you link to is helpful, [Orchestrating GPU-accelerated streaming apps using WebRTC](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/orchestrating-gpu-accelerated-streaming-apps-using-webrtc)

What they do to allow for `RTCPeerConnection` is:

Use two separate Node pools (group of Nodes):

- Default Node pool - for most components, using `Ingress` and load balancer
- TURN Node pool - for STUN/TURN service

### STUN/TURN service

The STUN/TURN service is *network bound* and deployed to dedicated nodes. It is deployed with one instance on each node in the node pool. This can be done on Kubernetes using a [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/). In addition this service should use host networking, e.g. all nodes has its ports accessible from Internet. Activate host networking for the PodTemplate in your `DaemonSet`:

```
hostNetwork: true
```

They use [coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn) as STUN/TURN server.

> The STUN/TURN service is run as a DaemonSet on each node of the TURN node pool. The coTURN process needs to allocate a fixed block of ports bound to the host IP address in order to properly serve relay traffic. A single coTURN instance can serve thousands of concurrent STUN and TURN requests based on the machine configuration.

#### Network

This part of their network diagram shows that some services are served over **https** with an *ingress gateway*, whereas the STUN/TURN service is through a different connection using **dtls/rtp** to the nodes exposed via host network.

[image: Network]

Comment: Thank you Jonas!! This is going to take me some time to wrap my head around, but I think that hostNetwork setting is key. I really appreciate the help. I'll accept and upvote once I get things working.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking for a solution to this problem: [STUNner](https://github.com/l7mp/stunner) is a new WebRTC media gateway that is designed *precisely* to support the use case the OP seeks, that is, ingesting WebRTC media traffic into a Kubernetes cluster. STUNner can be configured in the usual YAML-engineering style, it allows to run (and autoscale) your WebRTC media servers in ordinary pods, and it needs only *one* public IP and port for *all* media.

*Disclaimer:* I'm one of the authors of STUNner.