# How to configure Stun/Turn UDP port rang in ejabberd kuberbetes environment?

Tags: kubernetes, port, ejabberd, stun, turn

I'm trying to configure STUN/TURN in ejabberd which is running in Kubernetes environment. While we have to open a range of UDP ports for stun/turn configuration, in kubernetes I can't open a large range of ports in the deployment and service yaml files. I was thinking if opening range of ports in LB will work without opening in service yaml, but I'm not sure whether it'll work that way.

Please help in configuring stun/turn for ejabberd running in kubernetes.

we need to configure the stun/turn udp ports range (16500-32500) in ejabberd kubernetes server.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64232853/how-to-use-webrtc-with-rtcpeerconnection-on-kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge of kubernetes of the STUN/TURN part of ejabberd, so I sent your question to the ejabberd chatroom, and got a response from Saarko, a person qualified in those two topics. This is his response, let's hope it helps you:

> It is currently a mess, but the respective person may want to run a
> separate TURN server in k8s looking into this solution:
> https://github.com/l7mp/stunner
>
> It may be possible to trick their operator as well to use ejabberd as
> the corresponding TURN backend, but it is hacky
>
> l7mp/stunner also provide background information, why it is
> challenging to setup a TURN server in kubernetes